# Ionic Build failed :app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {@C:\MobileApp.Ionic\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\tmp\desugar_args3140882361716595656}
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s
(node:28480) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: try to remove the android platform of android and then re add it!

Comment: if that does not work go for gradle path setup and check that it is in the path or not!

Comment: getting same error. Removing android platform doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

try command `cordova clean android` make sure the user executes command has admin privilage